# Dynamic programming - fixed sum of fixed size array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic, dynamic-programming

Here is a problem I am stuck on:

> Two integers are given: N (the size of the array) and S (the required sum of all elements of the array)
>
> The requirements are to construct an array of size N and with the sum of its elements S in such a way that:
>
> - The array is to contain N *positive non-zero values*
> - The elements of the vector are distinct
> - The absolute difference between the largest and smallest element in the array is minimal
> - If there are more than 1 solutions in which this absolute difference is equal, the minim-lexicographic solution will be shown.

I can't really wrap my head around how to start the problem. Any help would be lovely.

Comment: The question is not appropriate. You cannot expect us to give the solution to your homework. Try something and show us if you do not understand anything.

Comment: Oh, well, I'm not really even sure where to start to be honest. It's not a homework, it's just a problem I hit and I can't wrap my head around where to start

Comment: Intuitively, if the size of the array should be, say 5, and the sum should be, say, 50, you could do with, [10,10,10,10,10]. Except that those are not distinct. So how to make them distinct, and make the difference between smallest and larges minimal? Well, isn't that just [8,9,10,11,12]?

Comment: Can you provide more details about the problem? how large are N and S?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sum of first N positive value {1,2,3...N) is `(N + 1)*N/2`

So, we can easily come up with a formula for sum of N consecutive positive numbers (starting at `a`)

```
((N + a - 1) + a)*N/2 = (N + 2*a - 1)*N/2
```

Using ***binary search***, we can find the N consecutive numbers with **largest starting number a** have sum <= S.

So let `dif = S - (N + 2*a - 1)*N/2` -> so the the last dif numbers should be add with 1 and the rest `N - dif` numbers are `N - dif + a, ..., a` .

Pseudo code

```
int start = 1;
int end = S;
int result = 1;
while(start <= end){
    int mid = (start + end)/2;
    int sum = sum(mid);   
    if(sum <= S){
       result = max(mid,result); 
       start = mid + 1;
    }else{
       end = mid - 1;
    } 
}
//So we know that the sequence starting at result
//Now we need to find the diff
int dif = S - sum(result);

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
   if(i >= N - dif ){//last N - dif number is added one
      print (i + result + 1);

   }else{
      print (i + result);
   }
}

int sum(int a){//Return sum from a to N + a - 1
    return (N +2*a - 1)*N/2     
}
```

Comment: We need to minimize the difference between the largest and the smallest element, so it looks like `diff` should be distributed as `+1` among the last `diff` elements of the array, not added to the last one.

Comment: @ILoveCoding modified my answer, so I added the different in last dif number :)

Comment: What does the "f" function do?

Comment: @Alexandr updated, it returns the sum of N consecutive numbers, started from `a`

Comment: @PhamTrung: this looks like a good answer, but without any prior effort from the OP, I am not entirely certain anything has been learned.

Answer (score 3):

I think that it is possible to do it by construction.

Take N = 6 and S = 30

1) Initialize your array like this : {1,2,3,4,5,6}

2) Loop and increment from the latest to the first :

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6} S = 21
{1,2,3,4,5,7} S = 22
{1,2,3,4,6,7} S = 23
{1,2,3,5,6,7} S = 24
{1,2,4,5,6,7} S = 25
{1,3,4,5,6,7} S = 26
{2,3,4,5,6,7} S = 27
```

Loop again :

```
{2,3,4,5,6,7} S = 27
{2,3,4,5,6,8} S = 28
{2,3,4,5,7,8} S = 29
{2,3,4,6,7,8} S = 30
```

Maybe there is a formula to find a good start. For example, you can start with :

```
 {S/N - N, S/N - N+1, S/N - N+2, ...}
```

Comment: You made your job easy by picking S that is divisible by N. What if S is 31 now?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Looping around seems to work fine. It will be {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9} for S = 31.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I rephrase the last sentence. The aim is not to compute an exact result but to find a good start for the algorithm. For example, if S = 10_000, it is useless to start with {1,2,3,4,5,6}. It will be better to start with {1660,1661,1662,1663,1664,1665}